# Modify the counts of some bins in a ggplot histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
df <- data.frame(a = round(rnorm(2000, mean=50, sd=5)))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=a)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=1)
```

I want to modify the count (i.e. height) of some bins in a ggplot histogram so that if the count of a bin is less than 25 but more than 0 it should be set to 25. Thus, the minimum non-zero count should be 25.

I'm looking for a ggplot solution, rather than preprocessing of data and using a bar plot instead.

Comment: You might have to use `geom_bar()` rather `geom_histogram()`. Traditional histograms have consistent scaling, unlike barplots where there is much more flexibility. Also, this may not be the greatest example data, as that normal distribution will rarely have observations less than 25.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  count(bin = floor(a)) %>%
  mutate(n = pmax(25, n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(bin, n)) + geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But this uses preprocessing before ggplot.